# search patterns with variable gaps in python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for patterns in a list containing different strings as:

```
names = ['TAATGH', 'GHHKLL', 'TGTHA', 'ATGTTKKKK', 'KLPPNF']
```

I would like to select the string that has the pattern 'T--T' (no matter how the string starts), so those elements would be selected and appended to a new list as:

```
namesSelected = ['TAATGH', 'ATGTTKKKK']
```

Using grep I could:

```
grep "T[[:alpha:]]\{2\}T"
```

Is there a similar mode in re python?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `/T.+T/` would do for the regex, assuming you want at least ONE character between the two T's. otherwise T.*T will handle `TT` as well.

Comment: Why does your title say "search patterns with variable gaps" when you only want to match patterns with two gaps?

Comment: Gaps may vary for other different selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can use `re.search`:

```
>>> names = ['TAATGH', 'GHHKLL', 'TGTHA', 'ATGTTKKKK', 'KLPPNF']
>>> reslist = []
>>> for i in names:
...     res = re.search(r'T[A-Z]{2}T', i)
...     if res:
...             reslist.append(i)
...
>>>
>>> print(reslist)
['TAATGH', 'ATGTTKKKK']
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is most likely what you want:

```
re.search(r'T[A-Z]{2}T', inputString)
```

The equivalent in Python for `[[:alpha:]]` would be `[a-zA-Z]`. You may replace `[A-Z]` with `[a-zA-Z]` in the code snippet above if you wish to allow lowercase alphabet.

Documentation for [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def grep(l, pattern):
    r = re.compile(pattern)
    return [_ for _ in l if r.search(pattern)]

nameSelected = grep(names, "T\w{2}T")
```

Note the use of `\w` instead of `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: That's true. [a-zA-Z] will match only alphabetic characters.